# Prime number distribution theory for dummies

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

For the distribution of prime numbers there is a hypothesis which predicts the possible positions of prime numbers called **Riemann hypothesis**

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers

Using **Fibonacci** it is also possible to 'predict' prime number positions by calculating the `gcd` of a Fibonacci number and a prime number.

From a computational standpoint it makes no sense calculating the `gcd` of a larger number solely to know the `gcd` of a smaller number.

**But is it true that from a mathematical point of view the primality property of the "position" is related to the Fibonacci number itself?** I understand that "position" in a set is a discrete value. But Fibonacci seems to make these values more continuous as they increase. Or is it in **no** way possible to relate an index number to an actual value?

> if x is prime then x = GCD(x, fibonacci(x-1)) or GCD(x, fibonacci(x+1))

What interests me most is the `true` which the above method returns for numbers which aren't prime numbers or prime numbers which aren't generated (I guess these are ***pseudoprimes***, but I'm not sure on the exact definition).

Has the *primal property* of **Fibonacci numbers** and the seemingly '*lesser and lesser occurrence of pseudoprimes as values increase*' been related to that same kind of '*increasingly better predictive  behaviour as the values increase*' seen in the **Riemann hypothesis**?

**Edit:** Or is this what Gauss and Riemann [discussed](http://www.math.uci.edu/~mfried/paplist-cov/Wh-Gauss-Tld-Riem-ab-Abel.html)?

### **Edit 2: More specific question for finding solution**

**The Riemann hypothesis:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhtcJPI6AtY#t=2485
[image: Still from Youtube video]

**Fourier transforms of Von Mangoldt function to produce spikes:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function
[image: Wikipedia image]

Now the Fibonacci pseudoprimes distribution also generates a certain 'pattern' (i've visualized it in the picture below). The pattern behaves the same as the Von Mangoldt function in the sense that the values stay within the horizontal hyperbole.

Thanks to Gerry Myerson I'm able to explain what I'm doing:

> let's call the Fibonacci pseudoprimes $ai$, so $a0=1$, $a1=323$, $a2=377$, and so on.   for each $n$ ,$n=1,2,…,$ I am plotting the point $pn=(n,an−an−1)$, and then I am drawing the line segment joining $pn$ to $pn+1$ for $n=1,2,…$

**"Fibonacci pseudoprimes produced 'random' pattern:"**
**Edit: Better graph for** `n<100000`

[image: Fibonacci pseudoprimes pattern]

Old graph (shows `n<1000000`)
[image: Fibonacci pseudoprimes pattern]

**Is it possible and does it make sense to apply the Fourier transforms mentioned above to the Fibonacci-pseudoprime pattern instead of the Von Mangoldt function?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pseudoprime"? In my opinion a pseudoprime is a composite number that passes certain prime tests, like Carmichael numbers or Knödel numbers.

Comment: Well they are actually also all the numbers generated by the formula stated. As the formula generates all primes but not all values generated are primes.

Comment: @Nimda, there is such a thing as a "Fibonacci pseudoprime", see, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Fibonacci_pseudoprimes ... but Ropstah it's not at all clear to me what that last picture is supposed to be.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: An alternative plot of the distribution of generated pseudoprimes which are not prime (as opposed to the ones which are in fact actually prime)

Comment: When you plot something, it is customary to label your axes. I still have no idea what you are plotting against what.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand. `X` should label 0 - 1M. The `Y` label is arbitrary as it's a pattern (or is this assumption incorrect?). The values represent: "The distribution of numbers generated by a Fibonacci pseudoprime algorithm which are -not really- prime". First of which being: (1,323,377,442,1891,2737,2834,3827,4181,5777,6479,6601,6721,8149)

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean. I don't know what 0-1M means. What in the picture corresponds to the Fibonacci pseudoprime 323?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Comment is wrong, i'm writing it again

Comment: I have no way explaining this recursion in mathematical language haha. Anyway the `1M` stands for `1000000`

Comment: Consider the array above input for `f(n)`. The function returns `f(n) - f(n-1)` which is basically the difference between the current and the previous value.

Comment: OK, I think we have established that you can't explain what you mean by "the Fibonacci-pseudoprime pattern". In which case, the question of whether one can apply Fourier transforms to it is moot.

Comment: I was told that the sequence which I was generating were so called pseudoprimes (based on: x = GCD(x, fibonacci(x-1)) or GCD(x, fibonacci(x+1)) -> if the above statement evaluates to 'true' then the value is 'produced' by the method. This method produces primes and a few other numbers). So it is a sequence based on Fibonacci and primality properties. Regardless of the name, the graph represents the distances between values in this sequence which is to my understanding the 'distribution'.

Comment: Maybe this will have no or perhaps a counterproductive effect but I am in no way mathematically educated besides high school. I understand that there are certain rules within science and mathematics which need to be followed to make things reproducible and/or scientifically usable however this is just play. This is not some assignment which I have to fix for school or some employer, I'm just playing around with some concepts. Don't get me wrong i don't want to be ignorant and I'm probably just wrong, but give it a try..

Comment: "the graph represents the distances between values in this sequence...." In what way does the graph represent these distances? If your sequence starts 1, 323, 377, ..., then what exactly in your graph represents the distance between 323 and 377? Is there a 54 in your graph somewhere ($54=377-323$)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I've added a more detailed version of the diagram

Comment: OK, let's call the Fibonacci pseudoprimes $a_i$, so $a_0=1$, $a_1=323$, $a_2=377$, and so on. Is this correct: for each $n$, $n=1,2,\dots$, you are plotting the point $p_n=(n,a_n-a_{n-1})$, and then you are drawing the line segment joining $p_n$ to $p_{n+1}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$?

Comment: So, did I give a correct description of your graph?

Comment: Yes that seems about just right! I wasn't able to just call the next sequence `n` :)

Comment: Good. So, please edit the question to include this description. People shouldn't have to wade through all the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Fair enough, hopefully this helps. Did it make any more sense to you or was your sole mission getting clear what the question was?